# How to include links to translations in HMENU sitemap?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I would like to create a sitemap via TypoScript which does also include links to all available translations.
Unfortunately the *special=language* feature does only work for the current page, not for multiple pages.
A combination of a regular HMENU with *special=language* menus in its items would be perfect.

My approach:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        expAll = 1
        NO{
            doNotShowLink = 1
            allWrap{
                postCObject = COA
                postCObject{
                    stdWrap.wrap = <url>|</url>
                    1 = TEXT
                    1{
                        typolink.parameter.field=uid
                        typolink.returnLast = url
                        wrap = <loc>|</loc>
                    }

                    2 < .1
                    2.typolink.additionalParams = &L=1
                    2.wrap = <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="|" />
                }
            }
        }
    }
    2 < .1
    3 < .1
}
```

That almost works, but unfortunately links will also be generated for non-available translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the translated page is exists using the typoscript select query :

```
2.if.isTrue.numRows {
    table = pages_language_overlay
    select {
        languageField = 0
        where = sys_language_uid = 1
        pidInList.field = uid
    }
}
```

Note: `languageField` is for selecting the language field, we need to disable in order to set `sys_language_uid` field in where clause. For disabling `languageField` we need to set `languageField = 0`. Check more information [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Functions/Select/Index.html?highlight=languageField#languagefield).

Answer (score 1):

As you already said: you generate Links for pages where no translation exists.
But you have the option to use conditions.

Add an `stdWrap.if` and check for existence of a translation of that page:

```
postCObject {

    : as above

    2.if.isTrue.cObject = CONTENT
    2.if.isTrue.cObject {
        table = pages_languages_overlay
        select {
           # get records in current page
           pidInList.field = uid
           # ignore current language
           languageField = 0
           # build individual selection on language 1
           where = sys_language = 1
           selectFields = uid
        }
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj.field = uid
    }
}
```